# Is there an alternative for using JSON + NSTimer for fetching datafrom server?

Tags: ios, json, nstimer, fetch

Im using NSTimer for constant data fetching from my server using JSON.

Using this technique has a lot of disadvantages, such as unwanted data fetching, and battery life drain.

An example of this usage is to get chat messages from the server.

**Is there a good alternative for constant data fetching?**

Thanks!

Comment: Sure. Fetching the data only when you need it.

Comment: that is the problem. I don't know when there is a new chat message.

Comment: an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), right? In this case, why don't you use some library for implementing the chat functionality?

Comment: could you please give an example?

Comment: [libpurple](https://github.com/felipec/libpurple-mini)

Comment: I'm sure libpurple is valuable, but the context here + github readme = gibberish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few alternatives to polling are:

1. have user ask for new data with a gesture,
2. APN - push when there's new data,
3. persistent connection.

Comment: hi danh, I think that a persistent connection might be the thing Im looking for. could you give an example of that?

Comment: Here's a promising looking library (with a decent read me) https://github.com/DyKnow/SignalR-ObjC/wiki/SignalR-Client.  I haven't tried it.